# Package in R to determine which factor values are overrepresented within a particular factor of interest

Tags: r, package, bioinformatics

I have performed some clustering using copy number data from SNP arrays. I would like to know if those clusters are enriched for any of the clinical data/factors the samples come with.

I have made several searches for a package that performs this, but results always are related to transcription factor enrichment.

Please, does anyone know any?

Comment: biostars.org might be more suitable.

Comment: Thanks zx8754, I will have a look